# Can I edit extended properties for a table using Management Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to edit the description of a table object using Mgt Studio with SQL 2008.

It doesn't look like there is a GUI was to do it anymore.

Am I missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right mouse click on the table and select "Properties". duh!